# Android RevMob Can't Display Advertisement

Tags: android, revmob

When i integrated the RevMob into my application, it shows me the following error :

```
No ads for this device/country right now
```

Is there a way to solve that issue ?

Comment: Hi There. Have u found a solution to it yet?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639186/android-revmob-cant-display-advertisement/15207123#15207123

Answer (score 0):

Do you give permition in manifest`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Comment: still its not displaying any banner ads can u please help me out logcat error is "Revmob did not answer as expected".

Answer (score 0):

It means what it says. Revmob doesn't have any publisher for your country. Revmob has invested much in gaining developers rather than advertisers, thus they have lack of ads sometimes.

Just to check if you have done everything fine, try using VPN on your device for UK or US. They normally have ads for those countries.

Answer (score 0):

To check the implementation you can use the test mode:

```
EnvironmentConfig.setTestingMode(true);
```

This is described on the sdk documentation [http://sdk.revmob.com/android](http://sdk.revmob.com/android#testing-mode)

Comment: my test ads (Banners) are displayed correctly but when i comment out the above line no ads are shown can u tell me why?

Comment: This can happen for different reasons, can you read any message on log cat?

Comment: @Diago Tridapalli  The logcat message is  "Revmob did not answer as expected".

Comment: I never saw this message, maybe they are having issues on their server. I suggest you to talk to them and then post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a temporary outage of campaigns for your device/country etc. It must be solved in the server/sales side automatically. But you can check your implementation using the testing mode, like Diogo said.

In the newest versions, you must use the following code:

```
RevMob revmob = RevMob.start(this, APPLICATION_ID);
revmob.setTestingMode(RevMobTestingMode.WITH_ADS);
```